# SwiftUI : QuickLook doesn't not work correctly in iPad device

Tags: swiftui, quicklook, ipados

I tried to using QuickLook framework.

For editting PDF, I implemented "previewController(_: editingModeFor: )" in Coordinator.

In Xcode(ver 11.6) simulator, quicklook view has pencil markup tool.
[In Xcode simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFhL8.png)

But in my iPad(PadOS 13.6), there is no markup tool.
[In my iPad device, PadOS 13.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCdpk.jpg)

Is there any bugs in QuickLook framework?

Here is my code.

PreviewController.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook
struct PreviewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        return navigationController
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {}
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDelegate, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
        let parent: PreviewController
        init(parent: PreviewController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return 1
    }
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    return parent.url as NSURL
    }
    /* 
Return .updateContents so QLPreviewController takes care of updating the contents of the provided QLPreviewItems whenever users save changes.
*/    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
    return .updateContents
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "LoremIpsum", withExtension: "pdf")!
    @State private var showingPreview = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Preview File") {
            self.showingPreview = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingPreview) {
            PreviewController(url: self.fileUrl, isPresented: self.$showingPreview)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get this working? im having same issue.